# Attempting to install Ubuntu on an HP Touchsmart TM2

Tags: boot, system-installation, laptop, hp

When I go into the setup utility I have the options: 
Main, Security, Diagnostics, System Configuration, Exit

This is different from what I've seen online when trying to find a guide.

But, in the System Configuration option I have a Boot Options section. So, I click that. I have a Boot Order option, so I click that. I get the options:
USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Disk, Notebook Hard Drive, USB CD/DVD ROM Drive, ! USB Floppy, ! Network Adapter

I tried selecting the USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Disk but when I restart it tells me "BOOTMGR is missing, restart"

I am at a loss. Help!

Thanks in advance. <3

Comment: Please provide more information like are you Using Windows 8, in UEFI mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows 8 in UEFI mode, you need to press F9 (for HP Laptops) to select your boot device, and you have to select an option like
`USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Disk **(EFI mode)**

Also you may need to disable the secure boot option from your Bios Menu, it would most probably be present under the **System Configuration** tab.

**Edit-**

Also *Enable Booting From USB*

and

*Disable Fast StartUp*

from your BIOS Menu.

You may also need to *Disable Secure Boot* from the BIOS Menu as well.

*To Bring Up the BIOS menu*, press F10 while booting( for HP Laptops)

*Note*--
You can check if you are running UEFI mode by going to the system bios by pressing F10 and checking under the **System Configuration** tab.

If you are facing any problems please let us know.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Windows 7 in UEFI. When I hit F9 I get "Boot Option Menu - Notebook Hard Drive," but that's it. I connected the flash drive to my desktop and it shows that it's properly set up as a boot disc. (see: http://imgur.com/dxAMsPq )

Comment: Yeah looking at your screenshot your USB Drive seems to be correct, however i think that booting from USB is not enabled. To enable it, fit F10 to bring up the BIOS setup while booting, and probably in the Boot or System Configuration Tab, there would be an option like- ENABLE Booting from USB. Tick it. There would also be an option like- FAST STARTUP, disable it. Now i think you would be able to boot from the USB Drive. Keep Us posted. And if my answer helped you, please mark it as solved if you successfully boot from the USB. :)

Comment: Perhaps it may be that you are not using UEFI mode, because I also have a HP Laptop in UEFI, and it displays several options like Boot from EFI file besides the NoteBook HardDrive Option.

Comment: And If you wanted to boot from a Live DVD, you will also have to Enable Boot from Optical DIsk in your BIOS menu.

Comment: It's potentially just BIOs. I'm not entirely sure what the differentiating aspects are, but I don't have a Boot option. The laptop doesn't have a disc drive, which is why I'm trying to use a USB stick.

Comment: When I pull up the BIOs it says "InsydeH2o Setup Utility, Rev. 3.5"

Comment: Under the System Configuration, there Boot Options could be present..you just need to Enable Booting from USB.

Comment: Sorry, yes, there is. But, I don't have "enable booting from USB", all I have it "POST Hotkey Delay" "HP QuickWeb (currently disabled)" "Floppy Boot" and "Internal network Adapter Boot" - the last two were initially disabled. I enabled them but it didn't make any difference. I do have the Boot Order  with USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Disk set already.

Comment: You need to enter the BIOS Setup, turn off your PC, and turn it on, and repeatedly press the [Escape] key..This would show various options like F9 Boot Menu F10 BIOS Setup....You then need to press F10 for the BIOS Setup.

Comment: Yes, that has been what I'm doing. So, I guess I've been in the BIOS the whole time.

Comment: There would be such a thing as BOOT ORDER...and in it there would be options arranged in a list like NoteBookHardDrive, USB HardDrive,USB Diskette...What you need to do is to push up THE USB HARD DRIVE option so that its the first one, i think you should be able to do this using F5 and F6 to move the entries up or down..

Comment: your Boot Order should look like- 1.USB Hard Drive 2.NoteBook Hard Drive and so on...

Comment: The Boot Order is "USB Diskette on Key/ USB Hard Disk" "USB CD/DVD ROM Drive" "Notebook Hard Drive" "USB Floppy" and "Network Adapter" - I don't have a USB disc drive, so the USB Hard Disk seems like what I would want. There's nothing anywhere about a flash or thumb drive, but I would assume USB Hard Disk would be the same thing. I could be wrong. Currently the USB Diskette On Key/USB Hard Disk is at the top (that was the first thing I did when troubleshooting)

Comment: Move up the USB Floppy option also, so thats its like 1.)USB Diskette on Key/ USB Hard Disk 2.)USB Floppy 3.)USB CD/DVD ROM Drive 4.)Notebook Hard Drive 5.)Network Adapter After that press Escape, choose the option "Save Settings and Exit" and restart. Perhaps it will boot...meanwhile I am searching on the net about your Laptop.

Comment: ! It did something new... but it seems to be frozen at the copyright line. "syslinux 4.06 EDD copyright"

Comment: Ok!..so now you are able to boot from the USB!!! I would suggest that you remake your USB Drive from windows again using the exact same steps as described in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows.. And if theres the same problem with the new made USB also, please open a new thread for it. And if I helped you, please Upvote my Answer and mark it as solved :)

Comment: Will do. Thank you so much for your help! I greatly appreciate it <3

Answer (score 0):

I've just bought HP TouchSmart today, there are no ticks like "Enable booting from USB" or "fast startup". So non of these advices worked.
What helped is - to enable "legacy support" and only then USB installer became available

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone is still in need of help with this, but all you have to do is:

1. Press <kbd>esc</kbd> on start up
2. Press <kbd>F11</kbd>
3. Select recover from CD/usb then install Ubuntu

Comment: I love that you get to the point quickly, and cut right to the chase, but if you could maybe provide a bit more explanation, what to do in other situations, add in the stuff after the initial answer that helps in a variety of situations instead of just this one. Welcome to the site and I hope to see even more content from you in the future! (both meanings included, pun both intended...and not)